# C - Como remover uma palavra de uma String

Tags: c, string, delete

Então, tenho que remover uma palavra de uma String, já adiciono com esse código:

```
printf("Digite o nome: \n");
scanf("%s", &temporaryVector);
getchar();
lettersName = strlen(temporaryVector);
temporaryVector[lettersName] = ';';
temporaryVector[lettersName + 1] = '\0';
lettersName = lettersName + 2;

name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (lettersName));

if (!name) {
    printf ("Erro, não foi possível alocar espaco.");
    return -1;
}

strcpy (name, temporaryVector);

oldSize = lettersName + oldSize;

firstAcess++;
} else {
printf("Digite o nome: \n");
scanf("%s", &temporaryVector);
getchar();
lettersName = strlen(temporaryVector);
temporaryVector[lettersName] = ';';
temporaryVector[lettersName + 1] = '\0';
lettersName = lettersName + 2;

oldSize = lettersName + oldSize;

name = (char*)realloc(name, oldSize);

if (!name) {
    printf ("Erro, não foi possível alocar espaco.");
    return -1;
}

strncat (name, temporaryVector, oldSize);
printf("%s\n", name);
}
```

No final de cada palavra eu adiciono um `;` para separar. Só que não sei como excluir uma palavra específica agora.

Comment: a resposta está boa, mas pra pontuar.. você colou um `else` logo após a linha do `firstAcess++;`.. esse `else` está perdido (não  associado a um `if`); provavelmente teria erro de compilação

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um pequeno exemplo com a implementação do método para remover uma palavra de uma frase. Espero que ajude.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//assinatura do metodo
void remove_palavra(char * frase, char * palavra);

int main()
{
    char * frase = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    char * palavra = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
    
    //Frase de onde queremos remover a palavra
    strcpy(frase  , "Teste para remover uma palavra da frase."); 

    //palavra que queremos remover da frase
    strcpy(palavra, "palavra "); 

    printf ("Remover a palavra'%s' da frase: '%s'\n\n", palavra, frase);

    remove_palavra(frase, palavra);
    
    printf ("Frase sem a palavra:'%s'\n", frase);
}


void remove_palavra(char * frase, char * palavra)
{
    int tamanhoFrase = strlen(frase);
    int tamanhoPalavra = strlen(palavra);
    
    // dá um ponteiro para o inicio da palavra
    char * ponteiro = strstr(frase, palavra);
    if(ponteiro)
    {
        //dá a posicao da palavra na frase original
        int posicao = (ponteiro - frase);

        //Incrementamos o ponteiro para ir para o fim da palavra procurada
        ponteiro = ponteiro + tamanhoPalavra;                
        
        //percorremos a frase e copiamos caracter a caracter do fim da apalavra para a posicao do incio da palavra
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < strlen(ponteiro); i++)
            frase[posicao + i] = ponteiro[i]; 

        //A frase agora tem que terminar mais cedo                
        frase[posicao + i] = 0;      
    }   
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Remover a palavra'palavra ' da frase: 'Teste para remover uma palavra da frase.'

Frase sem a palavra:'Teste para remover uma da frase.'
```